# how to get bootstrap datetimepicker selected date on input

Tags: jquery

i want to change the value of bootstrap datetimepicker input value from selected month and on change i have to perform some task on it

i tried on change function and assigning id to input but it won't work

```
`$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: "MMM-YYYY",
    viewMode: "months",
});`




    `$('#datetimepicker1').on('change',function(){
            var month=$(this).val();
            alert(month);
            $('#submit').show();
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo site_url('payment/get_payroll_by_month');?>',
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{month:month},
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $('td #employee').each(function(){
                        var emp=$(this).val();
                        var tr =$(this).closest('tr');
                        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            if(result[i].employee==emp)
                            {
                                tr.find('.status').text(result[i].status);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });`





`<div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="status">Select Month:</label>
                    <div class='input-group date'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' name="from_date"  />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

`

Comment: What exactly didn't work? What have you tried other than that? Have you researched anything? The more info you give StackOverflow, the more like we are to be able to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is `dp.change`:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.change',function(e){
    var month= e.date;
    alert(month);
    $('#submit').show();
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo site_url('payment/get_payroll_by_month');?>',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{month:month},
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $('td #employee').each(function(){
                var emp=$(this).val();
                var tr =$(this).closest('tr');
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    if(result[i].employee==emp)
                    {
                        tr.find('.status').text(result[i].status);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

See: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/

Comment: thanks for the solution can you please tell me alert on change function is not not showing month it set to input but it is not showing value in alert